# program get stuck after psql delete statement

Tags: c#, postgresql, ssh, sql-delete

My programm connects with ssh (ssh.net) to a host, with the data provider npgsql to a psql database and deletes an entry with a given ID.

It deletes the Entry as it should, but the programm get stuck after that for at least 1 min. With the **using** statement the connection should already disconnect after the sql-command i think, but i also don't get an error why it takes so long.

Is there something i forgot and have to wait for a timeout?

```
SshClient client = new SshClient(host, username, password);
```

try
    {
        //SSH Connection
        client.Connect();
        if (client.IsConnected)
        {
            scrLog.Content += "SSH connection successfull";
            scrLog.Content += Environment.NewLine;
        }
        else
        {
            scrLog.Content += "SSH connection failed";
            scrLog.Content += Environment.NewLine;
        }

`//Portforwarding to Port 5432 (postgresql)
    var portFwdL = new ForwardedPortLocal(psqlBoundHost, psqlUPort, psqlHost, psqlUPort);
    client.AddForwardedPort(portFwdL);
    portFwdL.Start();
    if (portFwdL.IsStarted)
    {
        scrLog.Content += "Portforwarding started";
        scrLog.Content += Environment.NewLine;
    }
    else
    {
        scrLog.Content += "Portforwarding failed";
        scrLog.Content += Environment.NewLine;
    }

    //Connection to Database with a Delete Command
    try
    {
        string connstring = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};" +
        "User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4}",
        psqlBoundHost, psqlPort, sqluser, sqlpass, database);

        using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            conn.Open();

            string sql1 = "delete from tblTest where testId = '" + nr + "';";
            //string sql2 = "\q";

            NpgsqlCommand cmd1 = new NpgsqlCommand(sql1, conn);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            scrLog.Content += sql1;
            scrLog.Content += Environment.NewLine;

            //NpgsqlCommand cmd2 = new NpgsqlCommand(sql2, conn);
            //cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //scrLog.Content += sql2;
            //scrLog.Content += Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error with the psql-connection:"
            + Environment.NewLine
            + ex.Message);
    }

    client.Disconnect();
    scrLog.Content += "SSH connection closed";
    scrLog.Content += Environment.NewLine;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error with the ssh-connection:"
        + Environment.NewLine
        + ex.Message);
}`

I tryed to use the

> \q

command in the end, but it gives me always the error "42601: syntax error at or near "\"" and i read that it isn't needed.

Can someone help?

Comment: You are mixing up psql - a command-line tool to access a PostgreSQL database cluster - and Npgsql - a software library to access PostgreSQL with C#. In Npgsql you cannot use psql commands like `\q`, you simply issue valid SQL commands. Also, if your `nr` parameter is some number (as may be the case), it should not be quoted. None of these explain the long waiting period, though. Please check the PostgreSQL log file for clues.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Patrick. In the log files, always i use the programm, it says after the waiting time `unexpected EOF on client connection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching and testing different scenarios, I finally found the timeout. I needed to disable the Connection Pooling, where the Connection is still open after closing, if it is needed again.
I just disabled it with `Pooling=false`.

```
string sqlpool = "false";
string sqlconn = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};Pooling={5};",
                    sqlserver, sqlport, sqluserid, sqlpass, sqldatabase, sqlpool);
```